# Javascript: Uploading a file... without a file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, extjs

I am trying to fake a file upload without actually using a file input from the user. The file's content will be dynamically generated from a string.

Is this possible? Have anyone ever done this before? Are there examples/theory available?

To clarify, I know how to upload a file using AJAX techniques using a hidden iframe and friends - the problem is uploading a file that is not in the form.

I am using ExtJS, but jQuery is feasible as well since ExtJS can plug into it (ext-jquery-base).

Comment: This seems like the wrong solution to your problem (if you have control of the server-side). If the file's content will be generated from a string, why not just POST that string and create the file on the server (using PHP or whatever)? 

If you are uploading a file to a 3rd party destination, then ignore this comment.

Comment: @JonathanJulian, no matter what, this usecase smells of real hack-value -), awesome trick!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Why not just use `XMLHttpRequest()` with POST?

```
function beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload(data)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://www.mysite.com/myuploadhandler.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            alert("File uploaded!");
    }
    xhr.send("filedata="+encodeURIComponent(data));
}
```

The handler script at the server just writes the file data to a file.

**EDIT**
File upload is still a http post with a different content type.  You can use this content type and separate your content with boundaries:

```
function beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload(data)
{
    // Define a boundary, I stole this from IE but you can use any string AFAIK
    var boundary = "---------------------------7da24f2e50046";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
             // Parameter name is "file" and local filename is "temp.txt"
             + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";'
             + 'filename="temp.txt"\r\n'
             // Add the file's mime-type
             + 'Content-type: plain/text\r\n\r\n'
             + data + '\r\n'
             + boundary + '--';

    xhr.open("POST", "http://www.mysite.com/myuploadhandler.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary

    );
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            alert("File uploaded!");
    }
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

If you want to send additional data, you just separate each section with a boundary and describe the content-disposition and content-type headers for each section.  Each header is separated by a newline and the body is separated from the headers by an additional newline.  Naturally, uploading binary data in this fashion would be slightly more difficult :-)

Further edit: forgot to mention, make sure whatever boundary string isn't in the text "file" that you're sending, otherwise it will be treated as a boundary.

Comment: Because the server will not recognize it as an uploaded 'file'.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to generate `data`.

Comment: @LiraNuna: Why does that matter if you're generating the content from a string?  Can't it just recognize it as a string and write it?

Comment: That would require me to change server-side code, which is in my case, impossible (remote service).

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something bad, but I just can't get the server to recognize the request as valid POST.

Comment: @Andy: It's okay, I had to read the RFC several times to get it working!

Comment: Just two minor corrections (I found a web application not accepting the above format): Contenty-Type should have  a capital "T"  and the last line of "body" should have two more dashes at the beginning: + '--' + boundary + '--';

Answer (score 48):

If you don't need support for older browsers, you can use the `FormData` Object, which is part of the File API:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
const blob = new Blob(['Lorem ipsum'], { type: 'plain/text' });
formData.append('file', blob, 'readme.txt');

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://example.org/upload');
request.send(formData);
```

File API is supported by all current browsers (IE10+)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

Comment: I avoid writing my own XMLHttpRequests. This is definitely my preferred answer!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - I spent 8 hours combing through various posts, and this is what worked, and in very few lines of code.

Answer (score 13):

Just sharing the final result, which works - and has clean way of adding/removing parameters without hardcoding anything.

```
var boundary = '-----------------------------' +
            Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 8));

    /* Parameters go here */
var params = {
    file: {
        type: 'text/plain',
        filename: Path.utils.basename(currentTab.id),
        content: GET_CONTENT() /* File content goes here */
    },
    action: 'upload',
    overwrite: 'true',
    destination: '/'
};

var content = [];
for(var i in params) {
    content.push('--' + boundary);

    var mimeHeader = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'+i+'"; ';
    if(params[i].filename)
        mimeHeader += 'filename="'+ params[i].filename +'";';
    content.push(mimeHeader);

    if(params[i].type)
        content.push('Content-Type: ' + params[i].type);

    content.push('');
    content.push(params[i].content || params[i]);
};

    /* Use your favorite toolkit here */
    /* it should still work if you can control headers and POST raw data */
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'www.example.com/upload.php',
    jsonData: content.join('\r\n'),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary,
        'Content-Length': content.length
    }
});
```

This was tested to work on all modern browsers, including but not limited to:

- IE6+
- FF 1.5+
- Opera 9+
- Chrome 1.0+
- Safari 3.0+

Comment: +1 Nice solution. But I think is something wrong with your algorithm. Why you use a `for in` for the params object? It seams like it's prepared for more than one file but the second file how will be named in the object? Where are `action`, `overwrite`, and `destination` used? and how they not break the code inside the `for in`?

Comment: @Protron: The reason I use `for( in )` is to get the keys from the description object. The code will detect if `filename` is set on a nested object (that describes a file to upload). The other parameters (`overwrite`, `action`, `destination`) are just extra parameters passed as if you used a form.

Comment: @LiraNuna, I see all you guys getting all magical about the `-----------------------------`, the only requirement by the MIME spec (see RFC 1341, sec 7.2.1) is that the the boundary commence with `--`followed by a valid token (see RFC 1341 sec.4). Hope this helps others know their freedom too :-)

Comment: Hi, this code isn't quite correct.
Content-Length is incorrectly calculated - it doesn't include the '\r\n' in the array join.
Also technically this doesn't do the boundary correctly. It should be '--boundary' initially, then 'boundary' between parts and 'boundary--' afterwards.
With these fixes it appears to work OK for me against Tomcat/JBoss.
Great work :-)

Answer (score 7):

A file upload it's just a `POST` request with that file content properly encoded and with an special `multipart/formdata` header. You need to use that `<input type=file />` because your browser security forbid you to access user disk directly.

As you don't need to read user disk, **YES**, you can fake it using Javascript. It will be just a `XMLHttpRequest`. To forge an "authentic" upload request, you can install [`Fiddler`](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) and inspect your outgoing request.

You'll need to encode that file correctly, so this link can be very useful: [RFC 2388: Returning Values from Forms:  multipart/form-data](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

Comment: What should go in that request then? how is that protocol defined? how to fake it?

Comment: that isn't a protocol, it's just a regular HTTP request; I updated my answer

Comment: I didn't use Fiddler (Linux user here), but Firebug does show how it should look. This brings me one step closer. I am upvoting as it is helpful, but not yet selecting the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Easy way to imitate "fake" file upload with jQuery:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var file = new Blob(['file contents'], {type: 'plain/text'});

fd.append('formFieldName', file, 'fileName.txt');

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/yourAddress',
  method: 'post',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,        //this...
  contentType: false         //and this is for formData type
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I just caught this POST_DATA string with the Firefox TamperData addon. I submitted a form with one `type="file"` field named "myfile" and a submit button named "btn-submit" with value "Upload". The contents of the uploaded file are

```
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
```

So here is the POST_DATA string:

```
-----------------------------192642264827446\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data;    \n
name="myfile"; filename="local-file-name.txt"\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
\r\n
Line \n
One\r\n
Line Two\r\n
Line Three\r\n
\r\n
-----------------------------192642264827446\n
\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="btn-submit"\r\n
\r\n
Upload\n
\r\n
-----------------------------192642264827446--\r\n
```

I'm not sure what the number means (192642264827446), but that should not be too hard to find out.

Comment: I reformatted the POST_DATA to make it easier to read, the 192642264827446 looks like a boundary marker

Comment: Thanks, gnibbler. Yeah, I thought it might be something like a boundary marker, probably just some random number.

Comment: Yeah, it's a boundary marker.  If you check the `multipart/form-data` header, the boundary will follow it.  The random number at the end is to avoid any conflictions with the data being sent.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2198524/2914587 worked for me, after I added an extra `'--'` before the final `boundary` in the payload:

```
var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
         // Parameter name is "file" and local filename is "temp.txt"
         + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";'
         + 'filename="temp.txt"\r\n'
         // Add the file's mime-type
         + 'Content-type: plain/text\r\n\r\n'
         + data + '\r\n'
         + '--' + boundary + '--';
```