# Connect to PHP Server using Swift

Tags: php, objective-c, swift

I have this script for Objective C to connect to server:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/project"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
  NSString *response = [request responseString];
  NSArray *results = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]; 
  for (NSString* result in results) {
   NSString * trimmedResult = [result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet   whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   if ([trimmedResult isEqualToString:@"failure"]) 
    NSLog(@"operation %i failed.", i + 1);
   }
 }
```

but now I need to use Swift. Is it easier to connect in Objective C and bridge to swift, or connect in swift? I would really like to just do it in swift though.

Comment: You are using third party library(which is outdated) `ASIHTTPRequest`. Since that library is written in Obj C, its better to bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your third party library, but you should be able to achieve the same with the built in methods, since it seems to be a simple synchronous request. Try this:

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://localhost/project")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

let results = NSString(data:reply, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// Continue your processing of results here...
```

**Update**
To use POST, employ an NSMutableURLRequest. General form is something like the following. The difficult to find part is *NSURLProtocol.setProperty(...)*. See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest).

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://localhost/project")
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

// set data
var dataString = "your data here" + boundaryConstant
let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

// set content length
NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

let results = NSString(data:reply, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: how would you pass a parameter through? like a POST parameter for username and password

Comment: hi grimxn , this is really useful , what's boundaryConstant for ?

Comment: It's a random string that delimits the data. Obviously there is a small but finite possibility that the string *will* appear in the data. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305218/what-is-the-boundary-parameter-in-an-http-multi-part-post-request