# HTTP POST multipart/form-data payload — What is that number [at thr end of the line]?

Tags: http, payload

So, here's the thing. I'm new to the whole HTTP payload data and have an example here from an HTTP Post:

```
-----------------------------34022565915738
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utf8"

✓
-----------------------------34022565915738
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="authenticity_token"

gqQVncnB9uY+UAfhauC4a9skcoNIP/2lvhMLaknFylHzjw8TwL6tW5qSSZtUJRjiDuFNb+E5rwuVoxMYmhd+Tw==
-----------------------------34022565915738
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session[email]"

*****.******@gmail.com
-----------------------------34022565915738
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session[password]"

***********
-----------------------------34022565915738--
```

What's up with the `34022565915738`? What is that? Because it changes every time I re-login. I just don't get it. Anybody have a hook?

PS: The whole point is: I want to be able to generate these programatically myself and for that I must understand what that number is.

Comment: The answer lies probably in the documentation of what you use to get this output; what I'm seeing is something that mixes HTTP response headers with some other output. At any rate, with the info you're giving, you're lucky if someone knows what you're referring to. **how do you get that output?**.

Comment: Its a *boundary* - a random value used as a delimiter in a multipart form, see [Example of multipart/form-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238809/example-of-multipart-form-data) and [What is the boundary parameter in an HTTP multi-part (POST) Request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305218/what-is-the-boundary-parameter-in-an-http-multi-part-post-request)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I copied it from Firefox login POST Data. My FF language is German so it says "Anfragenutzlast" right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I know. It's a random thing and could be set to anything but should not be anything that appears in the actual data.