# my server it looking for a file, but i have a string, How would i simulate a fileupload via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i was curious if there was a way for me to set up an ajax call such that a string would be recognized as a file.

i essentially created a XML via javascript that is in string format, and want to upload it, but the server looks for a file.

I was thinking that i would have to post it to a webservice such that it would post to a iframe as file contents or something and then upload it that way or some other hack around it.

**EDIT:**  I was thinking this might be a solution?  Creating a fake file?  [How to upload string as file with jQuery or other js framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012566/how-to-upload-string-as-file-with-jquery-or-other-js-framework)

Comment: Try it and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the same for how to upload a string as a file with Jquery and then looking at how the server processed the information.  I determined that the data saved doesnt nessicarily have to be that of a file.  When looking at responsees, all that information was in the string the next time it was pulled.  I actually just removed the data and pushed it up and it returned what i wanted.

```
var myData = {
   user: top.USERNAME,
   pass: top.PW_HASH,
   secure: true,
   url: top.BASE_URL,
   ext: "foo",
   data:saveXML
 };
```

which as you can see, the data being passed in the object to my $.ajax wrapper was just the saveXML.