# How to use superagent in browser to post a string as a file

Tags: javascript, superagent

I am trying to post a string as a file from the browser, as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012566/how-to-upload-string-as-file-with-jquery-or-other-js-framework)

But I want to use superagent to do this.  I tried the following:

```
var request = require('superagent');
var boundary = "---------------------------7da24f2e50046";

var req = request.post('/api/items');    
req.part()
    .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary)
    .set('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name="file"')
    .write('my-string')
    ;
req.end(function(err, response) {
    if(err) { console.err(err.status_code); }
    else { console.log(response.body); }
});
```

The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: req.part is not a function

Comment: SuperAgent runs on the server side. An alternative could be using jquery from a browser. See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I have used superagent in the browser for ordinary get and posts. But I cannot figure out how to use it for this particular use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In superagent project, there are two files: ./lib/client.js(using in browser), ./lib/node/index.js(using in node).  no part method in ./lib/client.js.

Comment: That explains my error. I ended up using plain XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: but how do I reference the object if I don't have `require('...')` ?

Comment: Sorry, found it: `var request = window.superagent;`