# HTTP Upload Techniques for 50gb files

Tags: http, upload, range, multipartform-data, chunked-encoding

I'm having some trouble understanding the underlying techniques involved in uploading a large (50gb) set of data over HTTP to a server, via a rest API.

I've been looking at Chunked upload and multipart upload.

Simply put, my understanding is that Chunked upload involves dividing the data into smaller chunks and uploading each chunk separately in separate HTTP requests and Multipart upload allows the transfer of multiple files types in a single request.

Is this correct?

Is there anything else i'm missing here?

I'm aware that practically this is done via a third party libs most of the time, what underlying protocols do [tus.io](https://tus.io/) use?

I've tried looking at the HTTP specs, but their not making much sense. Also looked at

- [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)
- [How does HTTP file upload work for large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952308/how-does-http-file-upload-work-for-large-files)
  with no luck.