# is it possible to send a DOM element with formdata?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

My question is how to send an element of a DOM using formdata object with a couple of other form data like input type file?

for exemple I want to send this HTML:

```
 <div><p>some text</p><span>other text</span></div>
```

Comment: Easily done with jQuery yes to answer yourquestion

Comment: What about a string representation of your DOM element? `document.getElementById('yourDOMelementId').outerHTML`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012611/4488121