# e2e $httpBackend fake file upload service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-e2e

I work on an angular front-end based on a fake backend implementation for development.

This fake storage is built using `localStorage` and the http request are handled by the [`e2e $httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend). All of this works nicely until i tried to fake a file upload service.

In my client code i have the following service ([based on this post](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });
    };
}]);
```

and the fake upload service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .run(function($httpBackend, $log) {
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('api/upload').respond(function(method, url, data) {
      // data is a FormData
      // TODO
      // read the content
      // store to local storage
      return [200, 'uploaded/path'];
    });

  });
```

The receive data is a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData). All i read around about `FormData` is that it is a write only object.

how can i read the file content to store it into the local storage ?

Comment: i'd like to see an answer to this as well

Comment: @Sevenearths you might offer a bounty ;)

Comment: I found what I was looking for here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198470/javascript-uploading-a-file-without-a-file

Comment: Unfortunately after the `$http.post` the request would be converted by XHR as a raw text request with multi-part form data with data being enclosed in the multipart start and end boundry. If you are interested in other solutions you will have to spell exactly what you intend to validate in your e2e test to narrow down the solutions. Are you trying to validate the contents of the uploaded file ?

Comment: You could inject your $httpProvider.interceptors and catch the inflight request or perhaps even cancel it faking that it went successfully or use your local storage to capture the request.