# PHP Guzzle. How to set custom boundary to the multipart POST request?

Tags: php, guzzle

How can I set custom boundary to the multipart POST request? Following request options configuration doesn't work.

```
'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=CUSTOM_BOUNDARY']
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you should be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is. API, that I should to use, requires that.

Comment: Sounds rather unlikely. Please cite the official documentation of that API.

Comment: Yes, I know =) But otherwise I get an error: "Content-Type does not contain boundary parameter". [API Docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References|_____116).

Comment: you should check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198470/javascript-uploading-a-file-without-a-file/2198524#2198524)

Comment: Thanks, I checked. The problem is that I can not able to set custom boundaries into the request body section ([Guzzle multipart request Docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart)).
Here is another question: how can I set a RAW HTTP body to the request with Guzzle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guzzle uses psr7 to combine multipart form fields into request body. The most correct way to deal with custom boundary would be using **GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream**.

```
$boundary = 'my_custom_boundary';
$multipart_form = [
    [
        'name' => 'upload_id',
        'contents' => $upload_id,
    ],
    [
        'name' => '_uuid',
        'contents' => $uuid,
    ],
    ...
];

$params = [
    'headers' => [
        'Connection' => 'close',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary,
    ],
    'body' => new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream($multipart_form, $boundary), // here is all the magic
];

$res = $this->client->request($method, $url, $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same error, here's how i solve it.

```
//encode field
$field_string = json_encode($field_data);
//read file
$file_string = Flysystem::read($config['doc_path']);
// hack, request body, inject field and file into requet body, set boundary
$request_body =
  "\r\n"
  ."\r\n"
  ."--customboundary\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
  ."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
  ."\r\n"
  ."$field_string\r\n"
  ."--customboundary\r\n"
  ."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
  ."Content-Disposition: file; filename=".$config['deal_name'].";documentid=".$config['deal_id']." \r\n"
  ."\r\n"
  ."$file_string\r\n"
  ."--customboundary--\r\n"
  ."\r\n";

//create request, boundary is required for docusign api
 $result = $this->client->createRequest('POST',"$this->baseUrl/templates", [
'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data;boundary=customboundary',
    'Content-Length' => strlen($request_body),
    'X-DocuSign-Authentication' => json_encode([
        'Username' => Config::get('docusign.email'),
        'Password' => Config::get('docusign.password'),
        'IntegratorKey' => Config::get('docusign.integratorKey')
    ]),
   ],
  'body' => $request_body
]);
```