# NodeJS Post Request with Content-Type: multipart/form-data Troubleshooting

Tags: node.js, request, content-type, content-disposition, dataform

I am trying to send dataUrl to a client's server.

The request is sent to a php script with **Content-Type: multipart/form-data** and a key/value message-body of **image=(dataUri string)**

If it has been successfully received a 10 digit number response is sent back.  If it is unsuccessful an error response is sent.

I am using the [datauri module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datauri) to generate the dataurl

If I attempt to do this via the terminal using the following:

```
val=`cat dataUri.txt` #generated via datauri module
curl -X POST -F 'image='$val http://xxx.yyyyyyy.com:8082/server/post.php
```

I am successful.

When trying using node and http.request I'm failing miserably :( . Through trial and error and loads of googling I stumbled on to --trace-ascii, which gives you a really verbose breakdown of the communication in terminal. So I have been trying to effectively copy the headers etc. in hope that I can make it work.

my request code looks like this at the moment:

```
    var body = 'image='+dataUri ;

    postOptions = {

        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------69b2c2b9c464731d' ,
          'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="image"' ,
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body) ,
          'Accept': '*/*' ,
          'Expect': '100-continue'
        } ,

        host: 'xxx.yyyyyyy.com' ,
        port: '8082' ,
        path: '/server/post.php' ,
        method: 'POST'
    } ; 

    // Set up the request
    post_req = http.request(
        postOptions, 
        function(res) {
            // 
          res.setEncoding('utf8') ;

          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
              console.log('Response: ' + chunk) ;
          }) ;

        }) ;

    // post the data
    post_req.write(body) ;
    post_req.end() ;
```

It fails every time.  Something I have noticed:  In terminal the Content-Length Number is larger than the one I get using Buffer.byteLength in Node by a couple of hundred bytes.

Sorry for omitting the server info.  I'm not sure if I am allowed to post it...

Can anyone give me any tips, any links to info I should read, keywords, anything really.  I have a long way to go with this pretty sure I should be using some type of abstraction like Express but you have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out.  the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198470/javascript-uploading-a-file-without-a-file/2198524#2198524)

I wasn't using **Content-Disposition** correctly. It isn't meant to be a header it's meant to be part of the message-body (which explains the larger **Content-Length**

correct code:

```
    var boundary = '------------------------69b2c2b9c464731d'


    var body = `--${boundary}
                \nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

                \nContent-type: plain/text
                \nimage=${img}
                \n${boundary}--`;

    postOptions = {

        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary ,
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
        } ,

        host: 'xxx.yyyyyyyyyy.com' ,
        port: '8082' ,
        path: '/server/post.php' ,
        method: 'POST'
    } ; 

    // Set up the request
    post_req = http.request(
        postOptions, 
        function(res) {
            // 
          res.setEncoding('utf8') ;

          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
              console.log('Response: ' + chunk) ;
          }) ;

        }) ;

    // post the data
    post_req.write(body) ;
    post_req.end() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas's answer helped me except one mistake(?)

The
`` \n${boundary}--`; ``
might should be replaced as
`` \n--${boundary}--`; ``