# Example of creating an http request that sends both text and file to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, post, servlets

Currently I'm trying to make a javascript button that when clicks sends an Http Post request to a javaservlet. I see how one can get a file ready to send from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198470/javascript-uploading-a-file-without-a-file). However, I don't know the syntax to have the form send both a file and text strings as parameters to a servlet.

Currently, I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```js
var form = document.createElement("Form");
form.setAttribute("Method", "POST");
var formData = new FormData();

var blob = new Blob(['Lorem ipsum'], { type: 'plain/text' });
formData.append('file', blob,'myfile.xml')
form.setAttribute("FIle", "myfile.xml");
form.setAttribute("contentTYpe", "text/xml");
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

However my servlet can't seem to grab these attributes. I keep sysout only null

Comment: I would capitalize the attributes correctly, too: `contentType`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your action URL as follow to send text in the same request:

```
http://www.test.com/yourServlet?param=iota1&param2=iota2
```

In the servlet you can fetch the data as follows:

```
String p1 = request.getParameter("param");
System.out.println(p1); // should return 'iota1'
```