# How to pass an IFormFile from an action to another action without the data being lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm implementing stripe in my action `ChargeFileUpload`, on it should return to another action and upload said file.

Note these are not real class names, its just for the purpose of explanation.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ChargeFileUpload(ProfileViewModel model)
{
            user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            string successUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}" + Url.Action("UploadFile", "Member", new { model.Obj });
            Session session;

            ... extra code..

}
```

Heres the thing, the ProfileViewModel contains an class which contains a file lets call the class it `ClassWhichContainsFile` and the object for that class `obj`.

On success of the payment, it goes to this method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(ClassWhichContainsFile obj)
{
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        if (user != null)
        {
            //add file to users account
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Profile", new { userName = user.UserName });
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I pass the `obj` to the UploadFile method, all the properties that I want are there, but the `IFormFile` is not. When I am in the `ChargeFileUpload` method the `IFormFile` is there.

How can I get my IFormFile to be passed to the `UploadFile` method correctly?

Comment: I'd suggest saving the file somewhere with an ID, and then pass the ID.

Comment: You really can't convince browser to re-send file second time in unrelated POST request. As @John suggested saving file on first request server side is really only sensible option. You can push file content to new page and construct POST request clients side (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198470/javascript-uploading-a-file-without-a-file/2198524#2198524) but that may take long time as you need to send same file 3 time between browser and server.